# Execute rest of the code after Response.End() Alternative?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse

I have following code to generate an excel sheet from the provided datatable and I modified it to generate two excel sheets.

```
  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                            GenerateExcelSheet(dt);
                        if (dtSplit.Rows.Count > 0)
                            GenerateExcelSheet(dtSplit);



private void GenerateExcelSheet(DataTable dt)
        {
            string fileName = string.Format("Foodlist-{0}.xls", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyy-hh:mm:tt"));
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

           //Code
 Response.Write("<table>");

            //My code goes here

            Response.Write("</table>");

            Response.End();
        }
```

From above code GenerateExcelSheet(dt); is executing and download the file but

`if (dtSplit.Rows.Count > 0)` and rest of the code is not executing. After research I found that Response.End(); cause to end of the execution the current page. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Overcome what, specifically?  `Response.End()` does indeed end the response.  If you're trying to send *two* responses for the same request then HTTP simply doesn't work like that.  Perhaps you want to put both Excel file into a Zip archive and return that instead?

Comment: @David I want to download two excel files at once. First one have different records and second one has the remaining records. Is there any way to achieve this without Zip method?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use Zip *specifically*, there are likely other archive formats you can use.  (Though they'd be less common than Zip.)  But if the underlying goal is to return multiple files to the user then you'd need to combine those files into a single response.  You could perhaps combine them into a single Excel file.  Failing that, a Zip archive is a pretty standard way of combining multiple files into one.

Comment: It's worth noting here that you aren't actually generating an Excel file, the content type you send just forces Excel to open the document and it fudges it into a format it understands. If you really want to generate Excel, you should consider using a library to do that, there are plenty of examples of how to convert a DataTable to Excel. Additionally, you can't force 2 files to be downloaded so easily, and certainly not in one request.